# How to retrieve from a POST call parameters with special characters

Tags: java, post

I'm sending a `POST` to a URL, with content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and in the `POST` body parameters I'm including some special characters (like '+' or '/'). These characters get replaced and instead of sending this:

> IQEAAAAAAPAwAACkAAgAFBoRs7uBp+QfWhMlIECvWSkYecAmAAEABAAAAAEABwAIAAABN+zvnLkABwAIAAABN/IV97gAAgAIL5fPC5UyYdQABAAgSlVOUFRTRElPUwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAEdXMAAQAEAARhMAAAAAgAGFVQMTA4Mi1CTFVTMzA5NjJfMDAAAAAAAAABAAQgAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAwAgBEAAgABJLoupYACAA4MDYCGQCF4DyVJ+rNZIwlm9UN9PgfPa4atwaQouQCGQCDyM0SOtwsvmmIkBVzFdcDM/Lgzb08WII=

It's sending this

> IQEAAAAAAPAwAACkAAgAFBoRs7uBp QfWhMlIECvWSkYecAmAAEABAAAAAEABwAIAAABN zvnLkABwAIAAABN/IV97gAAgAIL5fPC5UyYdQABAAgSlVOUFRTRElPUwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAEdXMAAQAEAARhMAAAAAgAGFVQMTA4Mi1CTFVTMzA5NjJfMDAAAAAAAAABAAQgAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAwAgBEAAgABJLoupYACAA4MDYCGQCF4DyVJ rNZIwlm9UN9PgfPa4atwaQouQCGQCDyM0SOtwsvmmIkBVzFdcDM/Lgzb08WII=

I'm storing the parameter on a String variable in Java. Please notice that the `+` gets replaced with a bare space and the `/` get replaced with `\/`. Please help. I'm

Comment: What code are you using to send the POST request?

Comment: Please post the code used to make the POST request

Comment: I found the solution to this which was to url encode the string before sending it. The owner of the original code was not encoding it, but sending the content type as URL encoded and during the decoding process all the special characters got messed up. Now it works. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try URLencoding the `POST`, but without seeing your code there's no way to tell if that will work.